# App crashes with SIGABRT only on App Review

Tags: ios, realm, facebook-sdk-4.0

I have a weird problem with my app. I needed to update the metadata on App Store connect and uploaded a new build to App Store. The only thing that was changed in code is two strings with version number. Everything else is exactly the same as a version that is live on the App Store (which works fine). I got a rejection with 2.1.0 Performance: App Completeness reason, turned out my app crashes on launch on reviewers device. I thought that this maybe a one time problem and tried to upload a new build with same results. Crash report looks like this:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Application Specific Information:
abort() called


Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                         0x1aaf29288 __exceptionPreprocess + 220
1   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x1c3c23744 objc_exception_throw + 60
2   Realm                                  0x1031d3f90 RLMAccessorContext::createObject(objc_object*, realm::CreatePolicy, bool, realm::ObjKey) + 1776
3   Realm                                  0x103212e1c RLMAddObjectToRealm + 264
4   RealmSwift                             0x1038784e0 Realm.add(_:update:) + 279776 (__hidden#4669_:438)
5   AppName                        0x10275cf5c _hidden#5641_ + 282460 (__hidden#5706_:442)
6   AppName                        0x1027dcd64 _hidden#12_ + 806244 (__hidden#1380_:0)
7   AppName                        0x10275d1bc _hidden#296_ + 283068 (__hidden#1380_:0)
8   RealmSwift                             0x103877d78 Realm.write<A>(withoutNotifying:_:) + 277880 (__hidden#4669_:255)
9   AppName                        0x10275d0f0 _hidden#5647_ + 282864 (__hidden#5706_:438)
10  AppName                        0x1028374a0 _hidden#15379_ + 1176736 (__hidden#15477_:382)
11  AppName                        0x102838824 _hidden#15383_ + 1181732 (__hidden#1380_:0)
12  UIKitCore                              0x1ad62f72c -[UIApplication _handleDelegateCallbacksWithOptions:isSuspended:restoreState:] + 340
13  UIKitCore                              0x1ad816564 -[UIApplication _callInitializationDelegatesWithActions:forCanvas:payload:fromOriginatingProcess:] + 3572
14  UIKitCore                              0x1ad7ff118 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1180
15  UIKitCore                              0x1ad65cd34 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer completeApplicationLaunchWithFBSScene:transitionContext:] + 152
16  UIKitCore                              0x1ad4b73b4 _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask + 104
17  UIKitCore                              0x1ad5e1d90 __101-[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:]_block_invoke + 216
18  UIKitCore                              0x1ad701aa0 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _performBlock:withApplicationOfDeactivationReasons:fromReasons:] + 248
19  UIKitCore                              0x1ad940764 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer _evalTransitionToSettings:fromSettings:forceExit:withTransitionStore:] + 772
20  UIKitCore                              0x1ad8cbd14 -[_UISceneLifecycleMultiplexer uiScene:transitionedFromState:withTransitionContext:] + 340
21  UIKitCore                              0x1ad4b81a0 __186-[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:]_block_invoke + 196
22  UIKitCore                              0x1ad5780d8 +[BSAnimationSettings(UIKit) tryAnimatingWithSettings:actions:completion:] + 892
23  UIKitCore                              0x1ad4ba0a4 _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContext + 276
24  UIKitCore                              0x1ad5a4244 -[_UIWindowSceneFBSSceneTransitionContextDrivenLifecycleSettingsDiffAction _performActionsForUIScene:withUpdatedFBSScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:lifecycleActionType:] + 384
25  UIKitCore                              0x1ada28e60 __64-[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.615 + 776
26  UIKitCore                              0x1ad4e8484 -[UIScene _emitSceneSettingsUpdateResponseForCompletion:afterSceneUpdateWork:] + 256
27  UIKitCore                              0x1ad52bcc4 -[UIScene scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 288
28  UIKitCore                              0x1ad661b38 -[UIApplication workspace:didCreateScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 584
29  UIKitCore                              0x1ad5a2508 -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:didInitializeWithEvent:completion:] + 388
30  FrontBoardServices                     0x1bd133294 -[FBSScene _callOutQueue_agent_didCreateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 440
31  FrontBoardServices                     0x1bd159090 __94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createWithSceneID:groupID:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.215 + 128
32  FrontBoardServices                     0x1bd114308 -[FBSWorkspace _calloutQueue_executeCalloutFromSource:withBlock:] + 240
33  FrontBoardServices                     0x1bd115958 __94-[FBSWorkspaceScenesClient createWithSceneID:groupID:parameters:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 372
34  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1aab90a30 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
35  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1aab944e0 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 264
36  FrontBoardServices                     0x1bd115c70 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 48
37  FrontBoardServices                     0x1bd115040 -[FBSSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 220
38  FrontBoardServices                     0x1bd119700 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 28
39  CoreFoundation                         0x1aaf4b414 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
40  CoreFoundation                         0x1aaf5c1a0 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 208
41  CoreFoundation                         0x1aae95694 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 268
42  CoreFoundation                         0x1aae9b05c __CFRunLoopRun + 828
43  CoreFoundation                         0x1aaeaebc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
44  GraphicsServices                       0x1c6fe2374 GSEventRunModal + 164
45  UIKitCore                              0x1ad81e648 -[UIApplication _run] + 1100
46  UIKitCore                              0x1ad59fd90 UIApplicationMain + 364
47  AppName                        0x1027211c8 main + 37320 (__hidden#1378_:63)
48  dyld                                   0x102ed5ce4 start + 520

Thread 0 name:   Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1e2965b38 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x21c0963bc pthread_kill + 268
2   libsystem_c.dylib                      0x1b602f524 abort + 168
3   libc++abi.dylib                        0x1c3d2eb7c abort_message + 132
4   libc++abi.dylib                        0x1c3d1e9c4 demangling_terminate_handler() + 336
5   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x1c3c29c68 _objc_terminate() + 144
6   libc++abi.dylib                        0x1c3d2df18 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 20
7   libc++abi.dylib                        0x1c3d2deb4 std::terminate() + 64
8   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1aab90a44 _dispatch_client_callout + 40
9   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1aab944e0 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 264
10  FrontBoardServices                     0x1bd115c70 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 48
11  FrontBoardServices                     0x1bd115040 -[FBSSerialQueue _targetQueue_performNextIfPossible] + 220
12  FrontBoardServices                     0x1bd119700 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 28
13  CoreFoundation                         0x1aaf4b414 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 28
14  CoreFoundation                         0x1aaf5c1a0 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 208
15  CoreFoundation                         0x1aae95694 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 268
16  CoreFoundation                         0x1aae9b05c __CFRunLoopRun + 828
17  CoreFoundation                         0x1aaeaebc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
18  GraphicsServices                       0x1c6fe2374 GSEventRunModal + 164
19  UIKitCore                              0x1ad81e648 -[UIApplication _run] + 1100
20  UIKitCore                              0x1ad59fd90 UIApplicationMain + 364
21  AppName                        0x1027211c8 main + 37320 (__hidden#1378_:63)
22  dyld                                   0x102ed5ce4 start + 520

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x21c08fe54 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x21c08fe54 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x21c08fe54 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1e295f4a0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1e295fae4 mach_msg + 76
2   CoreFoundation                         0x1aae96d30 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372
3   CoreFoundation                         0x1aae9b1bc __CFRunLoopRun + 1180
4   CoreFoundation                         0x1aaeaebc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
5   Foundation                             0x1ac69d464 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 236
6   Foundation                             0x1ac6dee2c -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 92
7   UIKitCore                              0x1ad798770 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 524
8   Foundation                             0x1ac6ed43c __NSThread__start__ + 808
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x21c0909ac _pthread_start + 148
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x21c08fe68 thread_start + 8

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x21c08fe54 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 6 name:   Dispatch queue: com.apple.UIKit.KeyboardManagement
Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1e2960138 __ulock_wait + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1aab91420 _dlock_wait + 56
2   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1aab911d4 _dispatch_thread_event_wait_slow + 56
3   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1aab9ff70 __DISPATCH_WAIT_FOR_QUEUE__ + 356
4   libdispatch.dylib                      0x1aab9fb28 _dispatch_sync_f_slow + 144
5   UIKitCore                              0x1ad6785ac __37-[_UIRemoteKeyboards startConnection]_block_invoke_3 + 136
6   CoreFoundation                         0x1aaeb1b24 __invoking___ + 148
7   CoreFoundation                         0x1aaecf610 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 468
8   Foundation                             0x1ac6b9938 __NSXPCCONNECTION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_REPLY_BLOCK__ + 24
9   Foundation                             0x1ac6daf74 -[NSXPCConnection _decodeAndInvokeReplyBlockWithEvent:sequence:replyInfo:] + 572
10  Foundation                             0x1ac6b5480 __88-[NSXPCConnection _sendInvocation:orArguments:count:methodSignature:selector:withProxy:]_block_invoke_3 + 212
11  libxpc.dylib                           0x21c0c56ac _xpc_connection_reply_callout + 124
12  libxpc.dylib                           0x21c0b8bcc _xpc_connection_call_reply_async + 88
13  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1aab90ab0 _dispatch_client_callout3 + 20
14  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1aabae214 _dispatch_mach_msg_async_reply_invoke + 340
15  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1aab98000 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 376
16  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1aab98cb4 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 444
17  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1aaba3500 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 648
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x21c0900bc _pthread_wqthread + 288
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x21c08fe5c start_wqthread + 8

Thread 7 name:  AVAudioSession Notify Thread
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1e295f4a0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1e295fae4 mach_msg + 76
2   CoreFoundation                         0x1aae96d30 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 372
3   CoreFoundation                         0x1aae9b1bc __CFRunLoopRun + 1180
4   CoreFoundation                         0x1aaeaebc8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 600
5   AudioSession                           0x1b44baf04 CADeprecated::GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 164
6   AudioSession                           0x1b44c48f0 CADeprecated::CAPThread::Entry(CADeprecated::CAPThread*) + 92
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x21c0909ac _pthread_start + 148
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x21c08fe68 thread_start + 8

Thread 8 name:  Realm notification listener
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib                 0x1e2960e18 kevent + 8
1   Realm                                  0x103528db4 realm::_impl::ExternalCommitHelper::listen() + 156
2   Realm                                  0x103528f04 _hidden#16050_ + 52
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x21c0909ac _pthread_start + 148
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x21c08fe68 thread_start + 8


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x00000001c3d320f5   x5: 0x000000016d6e6310   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000400
    x8: 0x54b9f472dc7144f9   x9: 0x54b9f473de83c179  x10: 0x0000000000000200  x11: 0x000000000000000b
   x12: 0x000000000000000b  x13: 0x00000001ab266a9f  x14: 0x00000001c3d3211b  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x0000000102f28580  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000000000103  x21: 0x0000000102f28660  x22: 0x0000000000000000  x23: 0x0000000102f28660
   x24: 0x00000002040a7000  x25: 0x000000016d6e6aa0  x26: 0x000000002b3100d5  x27: 0x00000002040a7000
   x28: 0x00000002040a7000   fp: 0x000000016d6e6280   lr: 0x000000021c0963bc
    sp: 0x000000016d6e6260   pc: 0x00000001e2965b38 cpsr: 0x40000000
   far: 0x0000000201cce768  esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault
```

Looks like Facebook SDK(?) crashing the app? And what is about Realm?
The problem is I can't reproduce the crash anywhere. Simulator or 5 real devices do not crash. I also see that Apple now use iPhone Xr as reviewer device (it was iPad before?). Tried to run app on iPhone Xr and it doesn't crash as well. Tried different combinations of Debug/Release, setting Exception Breakpoints without any luck.

Will be really thankful for any insight on how to approach this problem or what is going on here. Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you tried a test flight build?  The `FB` prefix in the crash log refers to *frontboard*, not *Facebook* - Front board is essentially the process that is launching your app.  The actual crash seems to be caused by an exception thrown by `RLMAccessorContext::createObject` - What does your app do with creating objects in Realm on launch?  Can you symbolicate the crashlog to see where in your app it was calling Realm?

Comment: There is likely something in common amongst those devices you're testing on - possibly some existing data the app needs or maybe even an updated Realm file. The tester is testing this on a totally clean device. So. Try to duplicate using that same criteria; ipe a device, starting from scratch. Put your app on it and try it. I will also agree with @Paulw11 - the issue seems to revolve around adding an object which again points to perhaps a Realm file version or Realm-code incompatibility.

Comment: @Paulw11 - thank you very much, FB info is really valuable as actually FB SDK was the last thing I have added to app and thought this can cause problems. TestFlight build works fine. The weird thing is the SAME code was approved about 10 days ago and it is live on AppStore and not crashing as well. Can you please point out how to symbolicate it further? I have added the crash file to logs window in xcode and it cleaned the file but not sure what to do next? Thank you very much!

Comment: @Jay - so i have tried on 2 my devices which have this app through testFlight before and asked three friends who does not had this app before and all works fine with them. Will try to reset one of my devices and see what happens. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure 100% if this is the fix to my problem as I was not able to reproduce this crash on any of mine or tester devices. However I had ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization in App Delegate which appears to be not the place where you should use it. I moved it to initial viewcontroller and this fixed this crash for me and app got approved. But again I am not sure if I am maybe just lucky this time because I was not able to reproduce it in anyway and the app with this function in App Delegate was in store before, but maybe it crashes sometime not sure. If anyone with more knowledge of what might happen can write in that can be helpful for future. Thanks everyone.